# Not understanding why I can call interface methods without concrete implementation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories, crud-repository

I am working on a Spring Boot application which uses Spring Data Jpa. I cannot give you the exact code since I am not allowed to, but I can simplify my issue so you may get an idea:

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM User WHERE u.uuid = :#{#uuid}")
Optional<UserInterface> findProjectedUserByUuid(UUID uuid)
```

This `Query` return an interface of type `UserInterface`:

```
public interface UserInterface{
    String getName();
    String getEmail();
}
```

Somewhere in my service class I get to this point:

```
UserInterface userInterface = userRepository.findProjectedUserByUuid(uuid).get();

System.out.println(userInterface.getName());
```

The application correctly prints out the name of the user.

My question is: why can I call `userInterface.getName()` in the code and return the correct name. Isn't this supposed to be an interface? How is it holding data?

My guess is...but I am not really sure about this, hence why I am asking you guys, this is a case of polymorphism. I believe that the repository is actually returning a class which implements my interface? And maybe that is why I am able to call methods on it. But if this is true, is there any way to see which class gets returned or use it in any meaningful way?

Comment: This is really a Java question. You can't instantiate an interface in Java, only a class that implements the interface. So yes the repository is actually returning a class (or strictly an object that is an instance of a class) which or a superclass of which is declared to implement the interface, and is (therefore) required to have implementations of the methods of the interface, optionally excepting those that have defaults (your example doesn't).